# Enable a Kiosk on Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, debian-based

I have a Windows app that runs great on Raspberry Pi 3 using Mono.  I need to have it run in Kiosk mode where users can't bail out to the OS. Is there a link or documentation on how to do this?  I guess I don't have to say that a Google search pulls up a bunch of junk - none of which I've been able to make work.

Since Raspbian is based on Linux Debian, if you have a solution for that I can probably make it work.